# Why isn't window.location.href working in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
 <script>
    logBox = new Vue({
    el: "#logBox",
    data: {
    email : '',
    password: ''
    },
    methods: {
      handelSubmit: function(e) {
           data = {};
           data['email'] = this.email;
           data['password'] = this.password;
            $.ajax({
              url: 'https://herokuapp.com/api/', //my url
              data: data,
              type: "POST",
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(e) {
              if(e.status != false){
               alert("Login Success").then(function() {
            // Redirect the user
            window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
            console.log('The Ok Button was clicked.');
            });
             }
              else {
                alert("failed to login!");
              }
          }
            });
            return false;
}
},
});
```

This is my login code. After a successful login, I need to redirect to a success page, but window.location.href is not working and I'm not able to direct to the new page. So, can any body please sort out my problem?

Comment: `alert()` does not return a promise. It's a synchronous function. So correct is: `alert(...); window.location.href = ...`

Comment: why are you using then? You can simply write code after alert statement and it will execute after that.

Answer (score -2):

`alert()` is not a promise. You should fix it to:

```
          if (e.status != false) {
            alert("Login Success");
            // Redirect the user
            window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
          }
```